# Trying run the for loop to match but always get "wrong" in result

Tags: python

```
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

import random

# Choose a random word from the list above:  
chosen = random.choice(word_list)
print(chosen)
lis = []
for c in chosen:
  lis.append("_")
print(lis)


# Get input from user and assign a variable to it. Make it lowercase.
guess = input("\n\nGuess the letter?\n").lower()
print(guess)


# Check the letter the user guessed and match it with the chosen one.
for char1 in chosen:
    print(char1, chosen)
    if char1 == chosen:
       print("ok")
    else:
       print("wrong")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `char1` which is a single character to `chosen` which is a multi-character string so it will always return `False`.

If you are trying to see if `guess` is in `chosen` you don't need the last `for` loop to at all:

```
guess = input("\n\nGuess the letter?\n").lower()
for char in guess:
    if char in chosen:
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("wrong")
```

Comment: I want to match single char with the whole string. If that string string contains that char then it should say match otherwise wrong. So what changes would be required

Comment: @StudyAll for that you dont need a for loop.  I edited my answer to show you

Comment: I am trying to iterate single word with whole string . In your solution it will match the whole word - for that I can also do - if guess = = char

Comment: @studyall I don't understand what you mean.  Can you copy some examples of the input for guess might be?

Comment: For the current for loop: if we pass single char like "a" and it's been compared with a random selection like "Camel", it says "a" is there. But when I try to pass the full name "Camel" it gives an error. So, what I'm trying to do is even if I pass full name it should iterate every char one by one with "Camel"!!

Comment: @Studyall Okay.... I edited to do what you want.  But it will print 'ok' on each letter.  Is that what you want or do you just want it to print ok if it all matches?